# Limit wifi bandwidth using router

Tags: networking

Here is my situation:
I have internet connection from my neighbour via Internet Connection Sharing from one of his modem port (LAN Cable and RJ45).
On my laptop I use a software (Connectify) so I can use the internet connection to the smartphone.

The problem is if I use smartphone (via wifi) to download something it suck all the bandwidth from my neighbour. And I don't want it happen.

What I want to do is:
Buy a router so I can limit my wifi bandwidth to about 500 kbps.

Is it possible...?

Comment: Yes, all depends on the router, but many do have the ability to throttle data. We do no recommend specific products here but you would be safe to chose any device that is well supported by DD-WRT or verify it has that capability in the stock firmware.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using an Android smartphone it's easier to use a Download Manager :

play store link:
http://www.google.com/url?q=https://play.google.com/store/apps/details%3Fid%3Dcom.dv.adm%26hl%3Den&sa=U&ved=0ahUKEwjZsdmEkMDUAhUUSWMKHb-aC9EQFggLMAA&sig2=j5qwoiYTY85-Mlq3xgetDQ&usg=AFQjCNFCVErmBuZSxLvKVouXFPQ-Yx-RpQ

You can limit speed of your downloads from setting options..

Answer (score 0):

Individual routers have different abilities, and some routers let you change the firmware to give you more abilities, like limiting bandwidth use by a particular device.  It's easier and more reliable to use a bandwidth limiter on the local trouble device or app.  For instance, limiting download speeds in a torrent app or using an Android bandwidth limiter app.